# gradle - create gzip for each file in a FileTree

Tags: gradle

I want to create multiple gzip file for each txt file in a `FileTree`. Here is my gradle task:

```
task gzipFiles << {
    FileTree tree = fileTree('build/dist') {
        include '**/*.txt'
    }
    tree.each {File file ->
        println file
        String fileName = file.getName()
        //create gzip file
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to use `Tar` task inside `FileTree` each loop to create a gzip?

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible - it will not work that way. What you can do is to *invert* the processing, here you go:

```
task all

fileTree('input') {
  include('**/*.txt')
}.each { f ->
  task "tar_$f.name"(type: Tar) { t ->
    from f.parentFile
    include f.name
    baseName = "$f.name"
    destinationDir = project.file('output')
    all.dependsOn(t)
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/38802186) is the demo.